# USB wire colors not matching standard colors: white, light-grey, blue, green; which is what?

Tags: usb

I have a USB cable with wires that have these colors:

- white
- light-grey
- blue
- green

I need to attach it to a USB cable with these colors:

- red
- black
- green
- white

What is the combination?

Comment: Time to pull out your multimeter and databooks...

Comment: what are these things? I'm not a technician :s

Comment: you don't have another end of secondary cable so you can't get pinout out from connector?

Comment: This is like the TV shows where somebody defuses a bomb by clipping certain color wires (because bomb makers always consult the bomb-makers' color code reference manual, and anyone else can just look up what standard colors they used).  If standard colors have been defined for a cable and you find a cable that doesn't match the standard, I wouldn't trust the colors.

Answer (score 11):

[This page on USBMan®](https://web.archive.org/web/20140214094305/http://www.usbman.com/Guides/BelkinMotherboard_cable_assembly.htm) seems to have the information you require, but the first set of colours do not make up a set of the four different wires, you seem to be missing at least a ground.

When there are non-standard colours floating about I would be very wary of connecting them up without finding out from the manufacturer what colour they are using for what.

- **Colour:** RED, ORANGE -> **Connects to:** POWER, VCC, SVCC, +5V
- **Colour:** WHITE, YELLOW -> **Connects to:** P-, DATA-, SBD-
- **Colour:** GREEN, GREY -> **Connects to:** P+, DATA+, SBD+
- **Colour:** BLACK, BLUE, BROWN -> **Connects to:** GROUND, GRND, GND

Comment: Now I made some mistakes in wiring wrongly. Then I attached my xbox controller s, and I wanted to know if I can broke it if I mix the wires?

Comment: Using a multimeter RED=ORANGE and WHITE=YELLOW on a mini usb cable I was splicing to a pc fan.

Answer (score 7):

There is no "always right" answer. They have to be checked. If you don't know what a multimeter is, you probably need help from someone more knowledgeable.